# Display predefined set of qestions in webform

Tags: webforms

I have requirement where customer wants to create a pool of questions/elements in webform and then create few sets of questions. Then randomly select one set of questions and display to user. I couldn't find a module/addon to achieve this.

Quiz module has similar functionality, customer is already using webform on multiple sites (using same codebase), quiz module is overkill for single webform.